# Gnuplot graph with circles, color and radius dependent on input

Tags: gnuplot

I have to make graph with gnuplot from some kind of input data. There is date, score and count for every entry. Graph should be with x axis representing date (I'll probably have question for that in the future too :/ ), y axis score and count should be represented by circles properly positioned in graph. The circles should have radius and color dependent on the count from input data.

Can anyone please set me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Edit:

Part of what I have:

```
set datafile separator ';'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H"
plot 'data' using 1:2:(some_function($3)) with circles
```

One line of data looks like this:

```
2014-02-21 19;0.5;5
```

However the circles seems like their radius depends on second column (0.5) instead of some_function(value_in_third_column), and I am not able to figure out where is the mistake.

Comment: If you don't show a full script, i.e. including the definition of the function, how can we know what you are doing? Remember, that the radius must be given in seconds when using time data.

Comment: Sorry, actually problem was in the function (used `^` instead of `**` )..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
plot 'datafile' with circles lc variable
```

(`lc` is short for `linecolor`) Type `? circles` and `? palette` at the gnuplot prompt to get started, and there are lots of examples online that should help you get an idea of how to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, however I still have some things I can't figure out - edited question :)